# Setup Macros in TeXstudio

Tags: math-mode, macros, texstudio

I created a little macro in TeXstudio for online math mode. I want to change the typical `$$` for `${}$` and I did it:

[image: Screenshoot 1]`

When I execute the standard macro for online math I get `$ | $` (*the `|` represents the cursor*), but when I execute my own macro I get `${}$|`. Someone knows if there is a way for executing my own macro and obtain `${|}$`?. Remember: `|` represents the cursor

Comment: What would be the reason for wanting `${}$`?

Comment: @egreg, when you use only `$$` and your equation is close to the end of the line, the equation will break in 2 lines. If you put your equation in the bracets `${ equation }$`, it won't break

Comment: You're using the wrong remedy and asking for bad typography.

Comment: @egreg your suggestion is let the online equation break in 2 lines instead of force to be in one line?

Comment: @DanielValencia Yes, of course. With `${...}$` spaces in the formula will not participate to stretching or shrinking in the line.

Answer (score 0):

@naphaneal answered the question:

For get the desired `${}$`, just add at the macro settings `${%|}$`and works perfectly